# Tuning memory config for Spark job and Hadoop Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, apache-zeppelin

I have to tuning memory config for Spark job and Hadoop Yarn. I have some input like this:

- 5 user interactive on notebook -> allocate same resource for each user + static memory allocation
- cluster config

```
1 master
   24 cores -> for other 8 => 16 cores
   64 gb -> for other 16 => 48 gb
3 slaves
   8 cores -> for other 1 => 7 cores
   32 gb -> for other 2 => 30 gb
```

- memory config for client mode

```
   yarn
       yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 30720
       yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 7
       
       yarn.schedule.minimun-allocation-mb = 2048
       yarn.schedule.maximun-allocation-mb = 8192
       
       yarn.schedule.minimun-allocation-vcores = 1
       yarn.schedule.maximun-allocation-vcores = 2
       
   spark
       spark.driver.cores = 2
       spark.driver.memory = 4g
       
       spark.executor.cores = 2 
       spark.executor.memory = 7g
       
       spark.executor.instances = 2
```

I caculated like that, am i wrong? Cluster still working, no memory error, but i feel it not optimal

Addtional, when i user regexp_extract function in pyspark, it run slowly

Comment: who can give me a hint?

Comment: who can give me a hint?

Comment: who can give me a hint?

Comment: who can give me a hint?

Comment: who can give me a hint, anyone ever work with spark, hadoop

Comment: who can give me a hint, anyone ever work with spark, hadoop